# Green tint on images in Firefox

Tags: graphics, firefox, 13.04, colors

I have had Ubuntu 13.04 for three weeks, I'm an absolute beginner. Some pictures (when browsing through Mozilla Firefox) have green tint. How to get rid of the tint? I didn't find anything on Google.

The hp indicator is an hp printer.

I checked in chromium - no such problem, it's ok.

Maybe the problem relates only to facebook.

I think the graphic card is dedicated as I have never done anything with it (actually, I don't know where it is).

[image: greenish images in facebook]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known](https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/766707) Firefox feature/bug. It is related to how firefox interprets color profiles. You have more information in the link, but to sumarize it you should disable color profile management in Firefox:

Type "about:config" in the firefox addresss bar. Search for "color". Double click on the gfx.color_management.mode option and set the value to 3. Then restart Firefox.